# how to derive the covariant basis in a coordinate system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products, tensors

i am trying to self study tensors, and I was wondering how would I go about with deriving the covariant basis in for example, the cylindrical and spherical coordinate system.

I'm watching the eigenchris series on Youtube so I was just wondering about this.

Any help is appreciated thanks~